# What is the absolute minimum content for web.config based url rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm going to be deploying an app in the near future on an IIS7 server, and would like to use the per-application URL rewriting settings in `web.config`, but this is **not** an ASP.NET application, so I have no need for anything superfluous.

What is the absolute minimum I need in my web.config in order to run my application and use URL Rewriting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of googling and stumbling through various articles, I've found [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/), which requires installing a URL Rewrite module (not packaged with IIS7). After that it's pretty simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule>
                    <match url="start\.html" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="finish.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I was pretty surprised that an extra download was required -- I thought this functionality was supposed to be baked in (testing on Win7x64). Oh well, at least it works.